# Deployment of Hibernate jar within an ear in JBoss AS7 failed

Tags: hibernate, deployment, ejb, jboss7.x, ear

I have an ear which contains only 2 modules : a jar containing Hibernate logic (named CorbeilleGestionHibernate.jar) and an EJB jar (named CorbeilleGestionEJBImpl.jar).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <display-name>CorbeilleGestionEAR</display-name>
  <initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>
  <module>
    <java>./CorbeilleGestionHibernate.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>CorbeilleGestionEJBImpl.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

My problem is that in the EJB jar I get access to an object in the Hibernate jar through JNDI.

This works great in local when starting JBoss in standalone mode. But when I start JBoss in domain mode I get the following error :

```
08:56:43,181 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."CorbeilleGestionEAR.ear"."CorbeilleGestionEJBImpl.jar".component.StartupBean.START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."CorbeilleGestionEAR.ear"."CorbeilleGestionEJBImpl.jar".component.StartupBean.START: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:116)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:130)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService.start(ComponentStartService.java:44)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: CorbeilleGestionHibernate -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.CorbeilleGestionHibernate
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:333)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.SingletonLifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonLifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: CorbeilleGestionHibernate -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.CorbeilleGestionHibernate
        at org.jboss.spring.support.SpringInjectionSupport.lookup(SpringInjectionSupport.java:180)
        at org.jboss.spring.support.SpringInjectionSupport.getObjectFromBeanFactory(SpringInjectionSupport.java:136)
        at org.jboss.spring.support.SpringInjectionSupport.injectToField(SpringInjectionSupport.java:202)
        at org.jboss.spring.support.SpringInjectionSupport.inject(SpringInjectionSupport.java:80)
        at org.jboss.spring.callback.SpringLifecycleInterceptor.postConstruct(SpringLifecycleInterceptor.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory.java:118)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory.java:112)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory.java:112)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: CorbeilleGestionHibernate -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.CorbeilleGestionHibernate
        at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:97)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:178)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:123)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:214)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at org.jboss.spring.support.SpringInjectionSupport.lookup(SpringInjectionSupport.java:173)
        ... 49 more
```

This error clearly means that the Hibernate jar is not loaded before the EJB jar.

I try to "force" the deployment by adding a dependency in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml like this

```
<sub-deployment name="CorbeilleGestionEJBImpl.jar">
    <dependencies>
        <module name="deployment.CorbeilleGestionEAR.ear.CorbeilleGestionHibernate.jar"  />
        <module name="org.jboss.as.webservices.server.integration" />
    </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>
```

but this doesn't seem to change anything.

I do a little search and it seems to me that Java modules don't respect the "initialize-in-order" attribute. Am I wrong ?

If I'm wrong I don't understand why the Hibernate jar is not loaded before my EJB jar.

If I'm not wrong what is the best solution to have my Hibernate jar loaded before my EJB jar.

To complete the question the object loaded from JNDI is an object defined in a Spring context. This context is defined in this jboss-spring.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Ceci permet de définir le nom JNDI -->
    <description>BeanFactory=(CorbeilleGestionHibernate)</description>

    <!-- Chargement des properties -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/corbeille/corbeille.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Pour pouvoir récupérer l'application context facilement -->
    <bean id="hibernateApplicationContextHolder" class="com.sham.corbeille.util.SpringApplicationContextHolder" />

    <import resource="*-config.xml"/>
</beans>
```

You can see we load all "*-config.xml", that is two files : db-config.xml and dao-config.xml.
The content of db-config.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:jboss/TransactionManager" />
        <property name="userTransactionName" value="java:jboss/UserTransaction" />
        <property name="transactionSynchronizationRegistryName" value="java:jboss/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionTranslator" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- JPA annotations bean post processor -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <!-- Exception translation bean post processor -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

and the content of dao-config.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Configuration par annotations -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sham.corbeille.dao" />


    <!-- DAOs Codification -->
    <bean id="elementCodifDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.codification.ElementCodifDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="sinCodTacheDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.codification.SinCodTacheDAOImpl" />

    <!-- DAOs Client -->
    <bean id="cliClientDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.client.CliClientDAOImpl" />

    <!-- DAOs Contrat -->
    <bean id="conContratDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.contrat.ConContratDAOImpl" />

    <!-- DAOs Flux -->
    <bean id="vueMessagesCorbeilleFluxClientDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.flux.VueMessagesCorbeilleClientDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="vueMessagesCorbeilleFluxSinistreDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.flux.VueMessagesCorbeilleSinistreDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="vueMessagesCorbeilleFluxUtilisateurDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.flux.VueMessagesCorbeilleUtilisateurDAOImpl" />

    <!-- DAOs Habilitations -->
    <bean id="habUtilisateurDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.habilitations.HabUtilisateurDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="habGroupeDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.habilitations.HabGroupeDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="habFonctionDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.habilitations.HabFonctionDAOImpl" />

    <!-- DAOs Historisation -->
    <bean id="sinHistoriseEtatNotifDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.historisation.SinHistoriseEtatNotifDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="sinHistoriseEtatMessageDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.historisation.SinHistoriseEtatMessageDAOImpl" />

    <!-- DAOs Notifications -->
    <bean id="sinNotificationsDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.notifications.SinNotificationsDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="sinMessagesDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.notifications.SinMessagesDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="notificationDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.notifications.NotificationDAOImpl" />

    <!-- DAOs Personne -->
    <bean id="cliContactsDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.personne.CliContactsDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="sinActeurExterneDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.personne.SinActeurExterneDAOImpl" />

    <!-- DAOs Règlements -->
    <bean id="sinReglementDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.reglement.SinReglementDAOImpl" />

    <!-- DAOs Sinistres -->
    <bean id="sinSinistreDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.sinistres.SinSinistreDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="sinProcedureDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.sinistres.SinProcedureDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="sinVictimeDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.sinistres.SinVictimeDAOImpl" />

    <!-- DAOs Vues -->
    <bean id="vueMessagesCorbeilleDAO" class="com.sham.corbeille.dao.vues.VueMessagesCorbeilleDAOImpl" />
</beans>
```

This is used in EJB to inject objects. For example to inject an object of type CliClientDAO we used the following annotation

```
@Spring(bean = "cliClientDAO", jndiName = "CorbeilleGestionHibernate")
```

These injections are the cause of the JNDI lookups which failed

If you need any further information to fully understand the problem ask me.

Comment: Would you mind to clarify what's the JNDI name that you try to load? Based on your description, it might be that the problem is not in the loading order, but in the wrong context for the JNDI. Also, would it be possible to also provide some logs, specially for the parts that got deployed ?

Comment: The JNDI name we try to load is "CorbeilleGestionHibernate". In fact in the Hibernate jar there is a Spring configuration file (named jboss-spring.xml) which defined the "CorbeilleGestionHibernate" object (with the line <description>BeanFactory=(CorbeilleGestionHibernate)</description>). This is the object we try to load from the EJB jar. I edit the question to add further details on this